# passing the value in the textbox failed in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to pass the data in the textbox using selenium web-driver.
i have used xpath ,id,name but none of them are working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='step2_portno_1']").sendKeys("80");
driver.findElement(By.id("step2_portno_")).sendKeys("80");


       > error:unable to locate the x path..
```

kindly help for the above issue.

Comment: What error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that selenium is not able to locate the element.
Once it gets the element, only then sendkeys would work.

Try below:

- Make sure that the element is appearing on the page when code is trying to locate it
- If the element is available but still 'unable to locate element' exception is thrown then make sure that the element is not inside any frame/iframe (You can check this by printing the page body on console using driver.getPageSource() and then manually searching element using ctrl + F.
- If the element is inside the frame then switch to that frame and then use finElement
- If the element is inside various Div then try to find div first and then search inside div.

Example:

```
   WebElement div1 = driver.findElement(By.id("myDiv"));
   WebElement myElement = div1.findElement(By.id("step2_portno_"));
```

Comment: HI Neha i have used the if method to do but the element is invisible..i will attach the code what i have written if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='actions clearfix']/ul/li[2]/a[@role='menuitem']")).isSelected()){
   System.out.println("visible");
      
  }else{
   System.out.println("invisible");
  } it is printing the else part so the element is not visible to the web driver but the element is editable manually ..kindly suggest me to solve this issue

Comment: isSelected() will not help us to identify whether the element is visible or not. Do one thing, Just before find element, print the page source on console and then manually search the element in printed content with Id. If you are getting it in page source that means the element is present on page. Also, in the snippet that you have posted i can see you missed few letters in Id while using By.id(). Just cross check.